# Cannot get this Typescript to compile

Tags: javascript, typescript, nightwatch.js

This is the compile error I get:

```
 error TS2339: Property 'waitForElementVisible' does not exist on type 'signinPage'
```

This is signinPage:

```
export class signinPage{
constructor(){
     emailInput: {
        selector: 'input[type=email]';
      };
      passwordInput: {
        selector: 'input[name=password]';
      };
      signinButton: {
        selector: 'button[type=submit]';
      };
}

signin(email, password){
    return this.waitForElementVisible('@emailInput')
      .setValue('@emailInput', email)
      .setValue('@passwordInput', password)
      .waitForElementVisible('@signinButton')
      .click('@signinButton')
    }


}
```

I think it does not know what 'this' is. I can't find anything relevant in the Typescript documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html)

This was converted from a working JavaScript project. The JavaScript version looks like this:

```
const signinCommands = {  
  signin: function(email, password) {
    return this.waitForElementVisible('@emailInput')
      .setValue('@emailInput', email)
      .setValue('@passwordInput', password)
      .waitForElementVisible('@signinButton')
      .click('@signinButton');
  }
};

module.exports = {   
  commands: [signinCommands],
  elements: {
    emailInput: {
      selector: 'input[type=email]'
    },
    passwordInput: {
      selector: 'input[type=password]'
    },
    signinButton: {
      selector: 'input[type=button]'
    },
  }
};
```

The TypeScript course tells me that JavaScript files can be used. This is simply not true, as this file does not work in a Typescript context. Lot of misinformation out there.

Comment: I don't see any declaration of `waitForElementVisible`...

Comment: @Cerbrus - I should not have to define waitForElementVisible. It worked in JavaScript!

Comment: @SteveStaple where is your definition of `waitForElementVisible` in JavaScript?

Comment: @SteveStaple: then you need to tell Typescript that the function exists.

Comment: @Cerbrus I believe waitForElementVisible is part of Nightwatch.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell the definition of that and initiate waitForElementVisible in typescript

```
export class signinPage{
    waitForElementVisible: (value?: string) => any;
    constructor(){
         emailInput: {
            selector: 'input[type=email]';
          };
          passwordInput: {
            selector: 'input[name=password]';
          };
          signinButton: {
            selector: 'button[type=submit]';
          };
          this.waitForElementVisible= () => {}
    }

    signin(email, password){
        return this.waitForElementVisible('@emailInput')
          .setValue('@emailInput', email)
          .setValue('@passwordInput', password)
          .waitForElementVisible('@signinButton')
          .click('@signinButton')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nightwatch.js is a JavaScript library. A JavaScript library does not contain type information. In order for TypeScript to understand `waitForElementVisible` and other nightwatch functions exist, you should install typing information by running:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/nightwatch
```

Then the workaround as specified by PlayMa256 is not needed.

Comment: I have updated my previous question, complete with an example of the problem at github. I would therefore like to close this issue, as I expect to find the answer with the previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669219/typescript-function-is-not-a-function-in-javascript-to-typescript-conversion

Comment: David Walschots - npm install --save-dev @types/nightwatch did not make any difference.

Comment: @SteveStaple according to the type definitions found [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/nightwatch/index.d.ts), `this` should be have the interface of `NightwatchBrowser`. However, in your TypeScript code, `this` refers to the type `signinPage`.

Comment: David Walschots - don't worry - the problem has now been solved. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669219/typescript-function-is-not-a-function-in-javascript-to-typescript-conversion